# How to call wpdb in a WordPress plugin class

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I call the `wpdb` inside a plugin function defined in a class like this,

```
<?php

/*
*   Plugin Name: Test
*   Plugin URI: http://www.test.com/
*   Description: Test plugin for wordpress.
*   Version: 1.0.0
*   Author: Test
*   Author URI: http://test.me/
*/      

class Test {

    /*
    |------------------------------------
    | Constructor
    |------------------------------------
    */

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function abc() {
        var_dump($wpdb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a global variable, $wpdb, 
which is an instantiation of the class already 
set up to communication WordPress database. 
Always use the global $wpdb variable. 
(Remember to globalize $wpdb before using it in any custom functions.)

You need to use it like this.

```
global $wpdb;
//do something with it.
```

Comment: Where to put this in my class?

Comment: at every places where you want to use
if you using in any function than put it in function or else in class.

Comment: Given the code example above please indicate how to access that global variable from within the plugin class.  Please show code.

Comment: You can pass the $wpdb global to your class when you instantiate the class
`    $example = new exampleClass($wpdb);`
Then in the constructor you can attach the $wpdb object to the class with $this->wpdb = $wpdb
`    public function __construct($wpdb){
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    }`